# Do I need to write all the properties explicitly when I am using AutoMapper, if these properties have the same name?

Tags: c#, automapper

I have been trying to get this going, but when i debug my test, the objects return null. I want to do complex object to object mapping but i cant get it to work.

Instead of:

```
cfg.CreateMap<Payments, Customer.Payments>()
    .ForMember(to => to.SomeName, opts => opts.MapFrom(from => from.SomeName))
    .ForMember(to => to.SomeDate, opts => opts.MapFrom(from => from.SomeDate));
```

We want to do:

```
    cfg.CreateMap<Payments, Customer.Payments>();
```

Comment: No, you **don't** need to map each member, it will work fine as long as the names and types are the same, that's the "Auto" part of "AutoMapper". If your tests are returning null there must be another issue, can you add a MVCE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd definitely checkout their [Wiki](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Getting-started) if you haven't already.

Based on your comment above, it looks like you're confused about the signature of `mapper.map`.

This is what you could do:
`var dest = mapper.Map<Dest>(new Source());`

Checkout this [simple fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kWFozZ#) for a working example based on the code you posted.

Comment: ProtipToSelf: Check documentations before coding. Not trial and error, it is essentially a waste of time when u can just read how the creators intended something to be.